# .NET regex into PHP - Issue grabbing dollar amount

Tags: php, regex

I am not very familiar in PHP and am kind of stuck grabbing a dollar amount from a sequence of text.

The text is as following:

```
Shipment price $11 Regular shipment
Shipment price $15 Express shipment
```

In .net I would use the following regular expression :

```
(?<=\$).*(?=Regular)
```

Which would output : 11
I am only trying to get the price (without dollar sign for "Regular Shipment". Is there anyone who can point me out how to achieve this in php ?

Many thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its similar in `php` too however you should use this.

```
(?<=\$)\S+(?=\s*Regular)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iV6mP5/4

```
$re = "/(?<=\\$)\\S+(?=\\s*Regular)/i"; 
$str = "Shipment price \$11 Regular shipment\nShipment price \$15 Express shipment "; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```